# Noun for "almost truth"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a noun for a statement that is false, but only because of a single, or a few, counter-examples?

An example of such a statement would be "All primes are odd." as 2 is prime and even, but it is clearly the only one.

Comment: I think the term is "false".

Comment: You could say "*All but* true".

Comment: (Or, if you must, "true most of the time", though that's a pretty wimpy statement.)

Comment: Mathematicians have a strange notion "almost all".  So... "almost all primes are odd"!

Comment: @GEdgar on that note, having studied mathematics myself, "Almost surely" did cross my mind, but I'm finding it hard to use repeatedly in an article explaining how "almost truths" are false.

Comment: "Save for one instance, all primes are odd."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a **noun** for a **statement** that is false?

[***Misstatement***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/misstate?q=misstatement#misstate__14) seems good.

Noun form of [misstate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/misstate?q=misstatement#misstate__14):

> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Make wrong or inaccurate statements about:
>
> *"All primes are odd," is a misstatement.*

*Misstatement* implies less intense condemnation of the error than *lie*, *falsehood* or *fallacy*.

---

***Fallacy*** implies the error of the statement is not in the statement *per se*, but in the logical underpinnings of the statement. That does not apply to your example, but could apply to the question.

---

An ***[Inexactitude](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inexact?q=inexactitude#inexact__6)*** might work.

Noun form of [inexact](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inexact?q=inexactitude#inexact__6)

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Not quite accurate or correct:

---

An ***[Imprecision](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/imprecise?q=Imprecise&searchDictCode=all)*** might be a good word for a sentence that almost gets it right.

Noun form of imprecise:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Lacking exactness and accuracy of expression or detail:

Comment: Not to say that these aren't just fine suggestions, but it's a good idea to wait a while (some say a day) before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you settle for an adverb?  Just throw in "essentially".  All primes are odd, essentially.

Comment: How does throwing in 'essentially' make a false statement acceptable?

Comment: It allows for inessential exceptions.

Comment: _2_ is not an inessential exception to the set of primes.

Comment: Yes, it is inessential.  "Prime" could have been defined as meaning "an integer not divisible by a different integer other than 1", with no harm done (except that 2 would no longer count as prime).

Comment: I should have said "(except that 1 and 2 would no longer count as primes)".

Comment: The definition of a prime is 'a natural number [1, 2, 3 ...] with exactly two [distinct] factors'. 1 is ruled out as it only has one. 2 is included as it has the required 2. No other positive even number c can be prime as it must have at least three factors: 1, c itself, and 2.

Answer (score 0):

"is nearly univerally true"
or

"is true in almost all cases"
or

"is, with few exceptions, true"